# How to add space between lines within a single paragraph with Reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab, paragraph

I have a block of text that is dynamically pulled from a database and is placed in a PDF before being served to a user. The text is being placed onto a lined background, much like notepad paper. I want to space the text so that only one line of text is between each background line.

I was able to use the following code to create a vertical spacing between paragraphs (used to generate another part of the PDF).

```
    style = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']
    style.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    style.spaceAfter = 15
    style.alignment = TA_JUSTIFY

    story = [Paragraph(choice.value,style) for choice in chain(context['question1'].itervalues(),context['question2'].itervalues())]
    generated_file = StringIO()
    frame1 = Frame(50,100,245,240, showBoundary=0)
    frame2 = Frame(320,100,245,240, showBoundary=0)
    page_template = PageTemplate(frames=[frame1,frame2])
    doc = BaseDocTemplate(generated_file,pageTemplates=[page_template])
    doc.build(story)
```

However, this won't work here because I have only a single, large paragraph.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pretty sure what yo u want to change is the leading. From the user manual in chapter 6.

> To get double-spaced text, use a high
>   leading. If you set
>   autoLeading(default "off") to
>   "min"(use observed leading even if
>   smaller than specified) or "max"(use
>   the larger of observed and specified)
>   then an attempt is made to determine
>   the leading on a line by line basis.
>   This may be useful if the lines
>   contain different font sizes etc.

Leading is defined earlier in chapter 2:

> **Interline spacing (Leading)**
>
> The vertical offset between the point
>   at which one line starts and where the
>   next starts is called the leading
>   offset.

So try different values of leading, for example:

```
style = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']
style.leading = 24
```

Comment: I read that paragraph three times before posting... Well, that's what I get for skimming documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add leading to ParagraphStyle

```
orden = ParagraphStyle('orden')
orden.leading = 14
orden.borderPadding = 10
orden.backColor=colors.gray
orden.fontSize = 14
```

Generate PDF

```
buffer = BytesIO()
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)

text = Paragraph("TEXT Nro 0001", orden)
text.wrapOn(p,500,10)
text.drawOn(p, 45, 200)


p.showPage()
p.save()
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
```

The result
[image]